# Order rows by ntile and row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to build stored procedure that will return data for Crystal Reports report.
Inside CR I'm using multi column layout.

I want to get 3 layout column something like this:

```
 1    5   8
 2    6   9
 3    7   10
 4
```

But because CR has some layout issues it is ordering my table like this:

```
 1    2   3
 4    5   6
 7    8   9
10
```

So I've tried to create procedure that will return extra column on which I'll sort my data.

So instead 1,2,3,4 order I need 1,4,7,10,2,5,8,3,6,9...

I have table with that data:

```
ID | CASE_ID |  CASE_DATE
--------------------------
 1 |   1     | 2014-02-03
 2 |   1     | 2014-02-04
 3 |   1     | 2014-02-05
 4 |   1     | 2014-02-06
 5 |   1     | 2014-02-07
 6 |   1     | 2014-02-08
 7 |   1     | 2014-02-09
 8 |   1     | 2014-02-10
 9 |   1     | 2014-02-11
10 |   1     | 2014-02-12
```

AND I need stored procedure that will return this data:

```
ID | CASE_ID |  CASE_DATE | ORDER
---------------------------------
 1 |   1     | 2014-02-03 |    1
 2 |   1     | 2014-02-04 |    5
 3 |   1     | 2014-02-05 |    8
 4 |   1     | 2014-02-06 |    2
 5 |   1     | 2014-02-07 |    6
 6 |   1     | 2014-02-08 |    9
 7 |   1     | 2014-02-09 |    3
 8 |   1     | 2014-02-10 |    7
 9 |   1     | 2014-02-11 |    10
10 |   1     | 2014-02-12 |    4
```

Here is sql fiddle with sample data and my code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c24c1/1

Idea behind sort column:

1. divide all rows into 3 groups (ntile), take first item from first group, then first from second and first from third group

**EDIT:**
Here is my temporary solution, I hope that running this will clarify what I had in mind when I was asking this question:

```
--DECLARE @NUM INT;
--SET @NUM=3;

SELECT ID,
       CASE_ID,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),CASE_DATE,121) AS DATA,
       (ROW1 - 1) * 3/*@NUM*/ + COL AS [ORDER]
FROM
  ( SELECT CASE_ID,
           ID,
           ROW AS LP,
                  COL,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_ID, COL ORDER BY ROW) AS ROW1,
                  CASE_DATE
   FROM
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.CASE_ID ORDER BY D.ID) AS ROW,
             NTILE(3/*@NUM*/) OVER (PARTITION BY D.CASE_ID ORDER BY D.ID) AS COL,
             ID,
             D.CASE_ID,
             CASE_DATE
      FROM DATA D
      WHERE D.CASE_ID = 1)X )Y
ORDER BY Y.CASE_ID,
         LP
```

Comment: what is logic behind order column ??

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar Crystal Reports is creating column across then down (as shown in second table, on top) if I want to get data displayed correctly I need to order it somehow. Idea is to divide all rows into 3 columns and then take first row after them place second row and so on. Sorry but I'm not speaking English native.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why is the second row given an ordering of "5"?  From what I can tell, you want the value in the first column of the second row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry for all the trouble. I have fixed table in my question

Comment: Is the order you need 1,4,7,10,2,5,8,3,6,9..., or 1, 5, 8, 2, 6, 9, 3,7 ,10,... ?

Comment: *"...because CR has some layout issues..."* Are these layout issues related to CR ignoring your design, or are they related to your not knowing *how* to get CR to do snaking columns? Because [CR can do that](http://computer-programming-forum.com/67-vb-crystal-report/8805b974da707cb8.htm).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I tried that, but I needed something different. If I have 5 items to display in my section they all were displayed one below other. If i had 100 items then "snaking columns" worked, but I needed this dynamic, so even if I have small amount of items they would be placed in 3 columns. My SQL allows that. Probably there are others way of doing that but I got that working with view (based on my code) as source for report. If You have other suggestions please write them as answer and I'll check it as solution.

Comment: You can set the height of various CR elements at run time, including the whole detail section.  Display-level issues like this aren't really suitable for SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  It looks like you actually want the `ORDER` column, not just returning the columns in that order.

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE_ID,
    DATA,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROW, N) AS [ORDER]
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
        CASE_ID,
        N,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_ID, N ORDER BY ID) AS ROW,
        DATA
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ID, 
            CASE_ID,
            NTILE(3) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE_ID ORDER BY ID) AS N,
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CASE_DATE,121) AS DATA
        FROM DATA
        WHERE CASE_ID = 1 ) X ) Y
ORDER BY ID;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c24c1/37)

Comment: I've added temporary solution, maybe this will clarify my question a bit.